# Textbook is showing a double quote by itself but when I try it gives a SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, eol

This book has twice now shown me `"` used by itself.

```
def chooseCave():
    cave = "
    while cave != '1' and cave != '2':
        print('Which cave will you go into?(Enter 1 or 2)')
        cave = input()
```

I get a SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
I'm unsure what to use in place of the single `"` to achieve what I would like.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is supposed to be two single quotes (`'`)

Comment: I've noticed that my kindle (or maybe its the format) seems to combine two single quotes into one double quote.

Comment: @Shadow spot on

Comment: @Kendas - that sounds like a very frustrating feature :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misread the book slightly.

You'll notice that they have used single quotes throughout the rest of the example to mark strings. I suspect that the first usage of this is no different.

The example is actually;

```
def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave != '1' and cave != '2':
        print('Which cave will you go into?(Enter 1 or 2)')
        cave = input()
```